# Woocommerce SKU or id?

Tags: woocommerce

I've been handed over a woocommerce website and a majority of the products are missing a sku number.

What would be the best way to go about updating products without a sku number?

Also keeping the skus unique?

Answer (score 0):

Best practice for SKU's is to use small, (mostly) meaningless codes with a uniform fixed length and pattern.

So suppose you sell less than 1000 products, take a code of 5 characters. And assign the codes automatically using a script:

```
10001 first product
10002 second product
etc
```

How these codes should be generated depends on you (business) domain model / woocommerce configuration (using variants yes/no). For inspiration see this project: https://github.com/tamarazuk/woocommerce-product-sku-generator

Comment: How about a function that simply makes SKU the product id?

Comment: Technically this is fine. However, id are not (always) good candidates for (customer facing) sku's because they differ in length (typically start with 1 up to maximum value of int or long) and/or are too long. But I do no know the details of your use case. Consider also something like sku = 10000 + id